# writing STDIN to process using its PID

Tags: c++, unix, process

I am trying to run GNU octave on one terminal window (window 1) and then send it commands from another (window 2). For example, setting the variable x = 1 from window 2 (possibly using the running instance of octave's PID) and then checking what x is in window 1 through the octave interface. Window 1 is essentially just waiting for a STDIN and I want to provide it from a different window.

I looked for a few hours on how to do this but everything I found tried solving different problems.

I am using the terminal on Mac OS X. My shell is Bash 4.2.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you need to also be able to type normally into window 1?

Comment: We would probably just have octave run in the background so we can access it from any window.

Answer (score 1):

I can't swear this will work on OSX, but on linux write to /proc/${pid}/fd/0.

Edit: actually this doesn't work.  Thanks @KeithThompson

Comment: I saw this on an ubuntu forum but, unfortunately, it did not work

Comment: That writes to the same device (e.g., `/dev/pts/1`) that the process is reading from, but the data written to the device doesn't show up in the process's `stdin` stream. Try `tail -f /etc/motd | tr a-z A-Z`, then `echo hello > /proc/<PID>/fd/0`; you'll see *lower case* `"hello"`.

Comment: i don't have the /proc directory - $ ls /proc
ls: /proc: No such file or directory

Comment: i remoted in to a server that uses ubuntu and can use /proc/${pid}/fd/0 to interact with the process. However, i'd like the output of the commands I sent it. Is there a way to grab this output?